# Replacing parts of a String

Tags: java, string

I need to find expressions like `"${someName}"` in strings in Java and replace them with some value. 
Currently, I am using `StringBuilder` along with its `indexOf()` and `replace()` methods to achieve the same.
But I would like to know if using Regex instead of all this will be better way of doing it or not.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be a [mcve]. StackOverflow is designed to **help** the people, not to work for they.

Comment: State your problem, provide the code and indicate your current output. It is a good way of asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard library in Java that will do that.  (There are 3rd-party libraries; for example [Freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/).)

I'm going to suggest a couple of alternatives in the Java SE libraries that you could use if you were prepared change your pattern syntax.

1. The `Formatter` class (and the corresponding `String.format(...)` shortcut method) will substitute parameters into a format string, while performing various value to text conversions.  It supports numbered and unnumbered positional substitution.   For example (taken from the javadoc):

   ```
    formatter.format("%4$2s %3$2s %2$2s %1$2s", "a", "b", "c", "d")
   ```

   produces

   ```
    " d  c  b  a"
   ```
2. The `MessageFormat` class has a simpler (cleaner) syntax.  For example (taken from the javadoc):

   ```
    int fileCount = 1273;
    String diskName = "MyDisk";
    Object[] testArgs = {new Long(fileCount), diskName};

    MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat(
        "The disk \"{1}\" contains {0} file(s).");

    System.out.println(form.format(testArgs));
   ```

   Produces output like this:

   ```
    The disk "MyDisk" contains 0 file(s).
    The disk "MyDisk" contains 1 file(s).
    The disk "MyDisk" contains 1,273 file(s).
   ```

   It can also do value conversion and formatting, and there is even a way to do conditional (choice) formats.